# What's the name of this pattern? (reused flyweight)

Tags: java, design-patterns

For years, I referred to this as *flyweight*, but looking for a good description of flyweight, I noted that they all said the basic use case was to create a lot of lightweight objects, whereas my motivation is to *avoid* creating a lot of objects.

The pattern is about using one object, or a small number of objects, for sequentially referring to different parts of a larger data structure under the guise of a specific interface. For instance, here is a class for an object that gives me a Number object that refers to parts (one part at a time) of a byte array for its actual data:

```
public final class LittleEndRef extends Number {
    private byte[] a;
    private int off;

    // This is the point: the fields are not finals, set in a constructor, which would require
    // creating a new object every time I want to address some postion of an array. I reuse the
    // same object to refer to different positions. (My motivation is to ensure that there is no
    // overhead from garbage collection, ever.)
    void setRef(byte[] a, int off) { this.a = a; this.off = off; }

    public byte byteValue() { return a[off]; }
    public short shortValue() { return (short)(a[off] | a[off+1]<<8); }
    public int intValue() { return a[off] | a[off+1]<<8 | a[off+2]<<16 | a[off+3]<<24; }
    public long longValue() { return a[off] | a[off+1]<<8 | a[off+2]<<16 | a[off+3]<<24 |
                              (long)(a[off+4] | a[off+5]<<8 | a[off+6]<<16 | a[off+7]<<24)<<32; }

    public float floatValue() { return Float.intBitsToFloat(intValue()); }
    public double doubleValue() { return Double.longBitsToDouble(longValue()); }
}
```

You could say this is an adapter, but it's a special kind of adapter in that it refers to part of a larger storage without duplicating the data, and also that it can be changed to refer to a different part, without creating a new object.

Any takes on how I should refer to that pattern?

Comment: Doesn't it suffer badly from race-conditions? I.e. it appears not threadsafe

Comment: Yes, you should definitely not pass these objects between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Feel like decorative pattern with Flyweight Pattern